# I don't understand C pointers

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I don't really understand the reason why I obtain a different address from what I'm expecting.

I've tried to build this small C code with `-m32` flag option.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *Buffer[10];

int main (void){
 printf("%p\n", Buffer);
 char *Buffer2 = Buffer + 6;
 printf("%p\n", Buffer2);
}
```

Expected output:

```
Buffer = 0x56559040
Buffer2 = 0x56559046
```

Obtained output:

```
Buffer = 0x56559040
Buffer2 = 0x56559058
```

Why the obtained output is different from the expected one (0x56559040 + 6 = 0x56559046)?

Comment: Because you have an array of *pointers*. Your pointers have a size of 4, `6 * 4 = 24` which is `0x18`. Pointer arthimetic works in units of elements, like array indexing does.

Comment: `Buffer` is an array of pointers. So the assignment `Buffer2 = Buffer + 6` should be generating a compiler warning about mismatched pointers. Be sure to enable the compiler warnings. With gcc and clang, you should be using the `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` command line options (as a minimum).

Comment: Didn't the compiler warn about -- `char *Buffer2 = Buffer + 6;` ?

Comment: You have an array of `pointers`, not `char`. How did this even compile? Seems like you should at least have warnings.

Comment: Don't ever ignore compiler warnings; they are usually a sign you've done something funky.

Comment: Change `char *Buffer[10];` to `char Buffer[10];`. I got the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between these two values

```
Buffer = 0x56559040
Buffer2 = 0x56559058
```

is `0x18` or in decimal `24`.

In this declaration

```
char *Buffer2 = Buffer + 6;
```

the array designator `Buffer` is converted to pointer to its first element. As the element type of the array `Buffer` is `char *` then the expression has the type `char **`.

There is no implicit conversion between types `char *` (the type of the variable `Buffer2`) and `char **` (the type of the initializer)

So the compiler should issue at least a warning.

Nevertheless using the pointer arithmetic this expression

```
Buffer + 6
```

is evaluated like

```
the value of the address pointed to by Buffer + 6 * sizeof( char * )
```

as the size of a pointer of the type `char *` (the size of element of the array) in your system is equal to `4` then you get the value 0x56559058 that is

```
0x56559040 + 6 * sizeof( char * )
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                       4
```

That is the expression

```
Buffer + 6
```

points to the sixth element of the array Buffer.